# Combining two queries that already use JOIN's

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two separate queries that I'm wanting to combine.

```
SELECT e.id, e.measurement, e.name, weight, time, reps, distance, exerciseid, DATE(date) as date
FROM `users exercises` LEFT JOIN exercises as e ON e.id = exerciseid
WHERE `userid` = '24' AND `date` < now()
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100

SELECT f.id, f.name, f.calories, f.protein, f.carbohydrate, DATE(date) as date, value, meal, unit
FROM `users foods` LEFT JOIN foods as f ON f.id = foodid
WHERE `userid` = '24' AND `date` < now()
ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 100
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 489
    [measurement] => 2
    [name] => Dumbbell Stability Ball Press
    [weight] => 20
    [time] => 
    [reps] => 20
    [distance] => 
    [exerciseid] => 489
    [date] => 2013-08-01
)

Array
(
    [id] => 7
    [name] => Cheese, camembert
    [calories] => 300
    [protein] => 19.8
    [carbohydrate] => 0.46
    [date] => 2013-09-20
    [value] => 23
    [meal] => 3
    [unit] => 2
)
```

Is it possible to combine these whilst keeping the same output?

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I do not want to join these queries together, **I'm not** after this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 672
    [measurement] => 1
    [name] => Ab Wheel (standing)
    [weight] => 
    [time] => 
    [reps] => 5
    [distance] => 
    [exerciseid] => 672
    [fid] => 23
    [fname] => Cheese, gruyere
    [calories] => 413
    [protein] => 29.81
    [carbohydrate] => 0.36
    [value] => 54
    [meal] => 1
    [unit] => 
)
```

I want to keep the arrays the same as they were from the original, but instead of using two queries, I want to use just the one. If possible.

Comment: Should be.  Also, we're probably going to assume MySQL (given PHP), but it's always good to state exact RDBMS vendor, in case of need of specific features (not likely an issue here, though).  What needs to happen when either side doesn't have a user/date (and where does `date` come from, and what type is it exactly)?

Comment: You could use a UNION for that: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp You might need to add some extra empty columns on both queries for the greatest common divider

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the date is a timestamp. MySQL is correct. The query will bring no results if the user has no entries.

Comment: @JasperSteenweg Thanks. Will read into this now.

Comment: @Chaplin - what should happen if there's a row for an exercise for a particular day/user, but no food?  Or vice-versa?  What's the expected number of foods/exercises per day - are you attempting to match up exercises with foods?  Otherwise, you actually do have _two unrelated queries_, and they should probably be left as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
(
    SELECT 'e' AS type,
            exerciseid as id,
            DATE(date) as date,
            e.name,
            weight,
            time,
            reps,
            distance,
            e.measurement,

            null as value,
            null as meal,
            null as unit,
            null as calories,
            null as protein,
            null as carbohydrate

    FROM `users exercises`
    LEFT JOIN exercises as e ON e.id = exerciseid

    WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` < now()
    ORDER BY date desc
)

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT 'f' AS type,
            foodid as id,
            DATE(date) as date,
            f.name,
            null as weight,
            null as time,
            null as reps,
            null as distance,
            null as measurement,

            value,
            meal,
            unit,
            f.calories,
            f.protein,
            f.carbohydrate

    FROM `users foods`
    LEFT JOIN foods as f ON f.id = foodid

    WHERE `userid` = $user->id AND `date` < now()
    ORDER BY date desc
)
```

Comment: No, a `UNION` is not the best option here, as the OP will need to stitch the result sets together in _PHP_, while the RDBMS could likely do this far cheaper (especially on larger sets).  Also, attempting to append the limit in this query will elicit... odd results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some things here, but you can join all of these tables together if they share the userid

```
SELECT e.id, e.measurement, e.name, weight, time, reps, distance, exerciseid, 
  ue.DATE(date) as date, f.id, f.name, f.calories, f.protein, f.carbohydrate, uf.value,
  uf.meal, uf.unit
FROM `users exercises` 
LEFT JOIN exercises as e ON e.id = exerciseid
LEFT JOIN `user foods` as uf ON uf.userid = e.userid
LEFT JOIN `foods` as f ON f.userid = e.userid
WHERE `userid` = '24' AND `date` < now()
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I'm fiddling with this to get it to work, but I do believe like the reply below, it'll output an array differently to how I want? I update the original question.

Comment: Ah, I see your update now.  Two outputs will typically require two select statements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can still join more tables, just make sure to give the tables the correct identification parameters. Untested longshot:

```
SELECT e.id, e.measurement, e.name, weight, time, reps, distance, exerciseid, DATE(date) as date,
f.id, f.name, f.calories, f.protein, f.carbohydrate, DATE(date) as date, value, meal, unit
FROM `users exercises`
LEFT JOIN exercises as e ON
    e.id = exerciseid
INNER JOIN `users foods` ON
    `users foods`.userid = `users exercises`.userid
LEFT JOIN foods as f ON
    f.id = foodid
WHERE `users exercises`.`userid` = '24' AND `users exercises`.`date` < now()
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100
```

I assume that it suffices that the two tables are linked by the userid, but as I don't know the content, I can't be sure about the date.

Comment: Thanks, but this outputs the array differently to what I'm after. I'm after the same output as the original.

Comment: You'll receive one result (one array in this case) per SELECT. I doubt that you can receive two arrays from one SELECT-statement. And I don't know why you would want that. The answers you received point you in the right direction, you can use the resulting array to extract all the data that you want.